# For the proof that $L^p$, $p≠2$, is not a Hilbert space, why the parallelogram law is violated?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces, intuition

For the proof that $L^p$, $p≠2$, is not a Hilbert space, I often see the parallelogram law cited. But could someone explain what is the intuition behind that, why the parallelogram law is violated? I have trouble understanding this.

Comment: You dont ask why stuff arent special you ask why they are! The fact that most spaces arent hilbert is the norm!

Comment: Try calculating some examples in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the $\ell^p$ norm $\| (x,y ) \|_p = (|x|^p + |y|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}$. This will build your intuition for what happens in the general case of $L^p(X,\mu)$ for $(X,\mu)$ a measure space.

Comment: Do you just consider Lebesgue measure? If not, what are your assumptions on the measure $\mu$? Note that there are measures for which $L^p$, $p \neq 2$, **is** a Hilbert space